# how to clear opencv CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE

Tags: opencv

always get delay frame after sleep while cv2.read,
have any solution to clear the `CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE`

```
while 1:
    ret, frame = capture_list[i].read()
    print(' [%d]   %s' % (i, ret))
    print(capture_list[i].get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why do you want to clear `CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE`

Comment: I want always get the newest frame from target video

Comment: how did you manage to clear?? Thanks

Comment: @CognitiveRobot I write a thread to read frame from openCV buffer as fast as possible, then put the newest frame to my own queue.